# How to list all labels in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want list all labels of **all resources**(include namespace, ingress, configmap etc.) in a K8s cluster, but I can't find easy way for that. Any K8s APIs provide similar feature? The labels result is unique better.

Comment: there is no easy way to do it. You need to go through all resource types.

Answer (score 4):

Use
`kubectl get all -A --show-labels`

get all -A will list all resources, with -A it will check in all namespaces, --show-labels will give display all labels in output.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by 'all' you can run something like that:

```bash
$ kubectl get all -A -o json | \
    jq -r '.items[].metadata.labels' | \
    sed 's/,//g' | \
    sort | \
    uniq
[list of all labels]
```

Otherwise you need to loop over every resource, but the rest would be the same.